# How AppEngine instances work on the local server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, instance

Newbie on appengine and I really don't know how to phrase the question which sadly results in me not knowing what keywords to google and I hope that i really do get help other than the bashing that a lot of people do.

I'm confused between the behavior of appengine online and the appengine on the local server.

**Background info**:
Btw this is in Python

Initially i assumed that , when needed or as authored
an instance of the app or module will be created.
And that instance will be the one serving multiple requests from different clients.

In this behavior any initialization code will only be run once.

But in the local development server.
Every time i add something new, specially in the main.py,
the server is able to catch the new changes,
then on browser-refresh be able to run it.

This made me think, wait...
Does it run the entire script over and over again
on every request?

**Question:**
Does an instance/module run the entire code on every request or is this just an added behavior to the dev server to make development easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your assumptions - about behaviour in production and development - are wrong.

In production, GAE spins up instances as required. This may be in response to increased load, or the host may simply decide after a certain amount of time to recycle an instance by killing it and starting a new one. Initialization code will always be run whenever a new instance is started.

In development, you only get a single instance. However, the server watches your file system for changes. If it detects a change to the code itself, it will restart itself, and therefore re-run the initialization code. But if you don't make any code changes between requests, the existing process continues indefinitely, and init code will not be re-run.